# Mixed Content warnings google fonts

Tags: migration, ssl, https

I installed a ssl certificate to my blog and moved everything from http to https. But I still get duplicate content warnings that the google fonts are loaded via http. I can't seem to find where I can change this.
I am using the theme SmartAdapt.
Can anyone give me a tip, where i can change these font includes to https?

Thank you very much,
Michael

Comment: This page is not about theme support. Please ask the theme developers to assist you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Search the place in your theme where you're including the google fonts script, and remove the leading part **http:** , at the beginning of google fonts api url.

The part you're going to leave should look like

```
//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family= and so on (leave what is after family but nothing before // )
```

Make a search replace in your theme to find